# problem with fetching data with laravel when i use relations and paginate()

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

what is error when i want to fetching data with **paginate(10)** the Vue js dosn't do it but when i use paginate(5) it working good this code of Controller with relationship in model files **and the response status 200 ok working**

```
$results = Posts::with(['comment'])
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(5);
        return response()
            ->json(['results' => $results]);
```

**this code is actually worked for me but i want to make 10 results in my page Like this**

```
$results = Posts::with(['comment'])
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->paginate(10);
return response()
->json(['results' => $results]);
```

with `->paginate(10)` or > 5 not giving any data and get error on console with Vue js but the response is ok 200 
 i make like this application without using vujs i used laravel from 3 years , sorry `dd()` and postman and all things used is done giving me the object json named `results { 0{} 1{} 2{} }` all working

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: how much data do you actually have for this query ? also put your vuejs code too

Comment: 25 records in database, the error after fetching data with axios give not found the post.comment.text

Comment: Make sure that all the posts have a comment. It could be that the first 5 all have a `comment`, but the next few don't.  If `post.comment.text` gives an error it could be that the `comment` is `null` and then it will give an error when trying to get the `text` from the `comment`.

Comment: `Teun :: ` you'r **master** that is my wrong thank you a lot

Comment: – Teun 
Make sure that all the posts have a comment. It could be that the first 5 all have a comment, but the next few don't. If post.comment.text gives an error it could be that the comment is null ______ how to fixed it if someone remove the comment

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTIONS

for pagination i will suggest you use jquery datatable for proper pagination. Its quite okay and saves lots of time. see below the sample implementation:

```
//this section call the document ready event making sure that datatable is loaded
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#').DataTable();
  } );

//this section display the datatable
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#mytable').DataTable( {
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
          "pageLength": 10, //here you can set the page row number limit
          buttons: [
              {
                  extend: 'print',
                  customize: function ( win ) {
                      $(win.document.body)
                          .css( 'font-size', '10pt' )
                          .prepend(
                              ''
                          );

                      $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                          .addClass( 'compact' )
                          .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
                  }
              }
          ]
      } );
  } );
</script>

//you can display record on the datatable after querying from your cntroller as shown below
<div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
 <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
                                            <thead>
                                              <tr bgcolor="#c7c7c7">
                                                <th>S/N</th>
                                                 <th>Name</th>
                                              </tr>
                                            </thead>

                                            <tbody>

                                              @php
                                              $i=1;
                                              @endphp
                                                @foreach($queryrecord as $list)

                                                   <tr>
                                                   <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
                                                   <td>{{ $list->name }}</td>
                                                   </tr>
                                               @endforeach
                                                </tbody>

                                          </table>
                                           <hr />
                                        </div>
```

Comment: thank you for answer me but i used Vuejs & axios my problem its not for make pagination pages the problem with fetching data with axios all record its ok showing and also with response i have all my data json but when i try to get
post.comment.text it got error on vue  not found post.comment.text